# Can someone explain this multithreading code in C?

Tags: c

I am having a really hard time understanding multithread code. I have this example code where I am supposed to be able to explain what output is written on the two commented lines. Can someone explain how I can determine the output here?

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int value = 0;

void *runner(void *param);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t pid;
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pid = fork();
    
    if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid,NULL);
        printf("CHILD: value = %d",value); /* LINE C */
        }
    else if (pid > 0){ /* parent process */
        wait(NULL);
        printf("PARENT: value = %d",value); /* LINE P */
    }}

void *runner(void *param){
    value = 5;
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for every one of those function calls that you don't already understand.  Important ones are `fork`, `pthread_create`, `pthread_join` and `wait`.  Once you've learned how these functions behave, you can then work out what this program will do.  As pointed out below, the program is a bit wack: you seem to have converted all the underscores into spaces...

Comment: That will be hard. It's not valid C.  You should devote your time to correct programs.

Comment: @Gene For the most part it's valid C, they forgot the `_` in some of the decleration and function calls.

Answer (score 4):

- The process starts.  It forks into a child process as well.

  - The parent process waits for the child process to finish.

    - The child process starts a thread and waits for it to complete via pthread_join

      - The thread sets the global memory variable, `value`, to `5`.
      - The thread exits
    - The child process, upon returning from pthread_join, prints `"CHILD: value = 5"`.
    - The child process exits.
  - The parent process, upon returning from wait, prints: `"PARENT: value = 0"`. `value` is 0 since processes don not the same memory space with other processes. (Threads in the same process share the same memory space).
- The parent process exits

Minor nit: The fact that the child process doesn't print an end of line char, `\n`, might create some weird overlapping results on the console.  Consider adding a `\n` to each printf statement.